# Is there a way to copy assets to a project via dependency?

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I'm currently working on an npm module that I'll bring into my app as a dependency.

This module is essentially a shared Gulp instance. The way that I have this setup, I would like to be able to copy over a Gulpfile.js into the app's root after the dependency is installed.

Is there a way to do this (`postinstall` maybe)? Is there a *better* way to go about this?

Example:

*App*: `npm install mySharedGulp`

*mySharedGulp is installed*

*postinstall script copies `Gulpfile.js` from *mySharedGulp* into app root.*

*user can then run Gulp commands no problem*

Comment: I don't think what you're trying to achieve is the best idea, but symlinking the file might better than copying the file. At least that way you would benefit from changes pulled in during `npm update`.

Comment: That's not a bad idea at all. Could I use `postinstall` to build that symlink then? Would that be a sanctioned practice?